# Issue when trying to requery on postID using facebook graph

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Forgive me I'm new to the Facebook graph concept. I've read through the documentation and am a little lost on something that I want to try and do. I have been able to query posts based on a keyword such as "sailing" like so:

> http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=sailing&type=post

I see that it returns a result set containing 25 of the most recent posts with the keyword provided. My issue comes when I try to take a post id and query it directly. What I want to do is to be able to take a post id and query it after a 24hr time frame to see if it has received any comments and to see how many likes it has gained since being posted.

I can take the userID_postID and query like:

> http://www.facebook.com/userID/posts/postID

I can see the post with the likes but when I try this in the graph:

> http://graph.facebook.com/userID/posts/postID

I get the following error message:

```
{
      "error": 
       {
          "message": "Unknown path components: / postID",
          "type": "OAuthException",
          "code": 2500
       }
}
```

I've seen where people have commented that if you want to access a post you will need to get an access_token. I'm not sure why you need an access_token to access a post that you originally obtained without one. It doesn't seem to make sense. One thing that I have noticed when trying to do this with different posts is that this seems to be related to accessing posts of an individual rather than a fan page. Whereas a public page such as a fan page seems to return the results.

I also tried querying like:

> http://graph.facebook.com/userID_postID/likes

this returns the likes for a public page such as a fan page but doesn't return anything for an individual page. Can anyone help point me in the right direction or maybe give me some explanation on what the proper way to handle this would be? Requesting an access_token from the user is something I do not want to do, this is mainly for a service that we're trying to create that allows us to survey based on a keyword. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.